# How to tell if code is already deployed by create2 at an address

Tags: openzeppelin, create2

We have a factory creating clones using `create2`, using OpenZeppelin's Clones (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#Clones-cloneDeterministic-address-bytes32-). Is it possible to know whether create2 has already been called with the same parameters in solidity? I.e. if given the address from `predictDeterministicAddress()`, is there a way to tell if there is code already deployed there without a revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the address has associated code: `account.code.length > 0`.

This is the way OpenZeppelin also does it. Do note that there are some minor caveats to this functionality, check the comments for their function: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/36951d58386b9fee81b237e6c6626c9115ccef3a/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L36

Comment: That will work perfectly for our use case. even given the caveats. Thank you!